# WHERE clause on or off depending on variable

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, global-variables, where-clause, case-when

Hi I am using SQL server 2008 R2. Would like to do the following:

```
declare
    -- only one of these @ vars will be used
    @specificAccountNumber int = NULL
    @specificAccountNumber int = 123456


select
    account
    ,accountinfo1
    ,accountinfo2
from tableA
where
    if @specificAccountNumber is NULL
    then use the whole table
    else /* @specificaAccountNumber is not null */
    account = @specificAccountNumber


select
    account
    ,accountinfo3
    ,accountinfo4
from tableB
where
    if @specificAccountNumber is NULL
    then use the whole table
    else /* @specificAccountNumber is not null */
    account = @specificAccountNumber
```

The goal is for the queries to select all rows if I don't speicify an account number (or set @specificAccountNumber to NULL), but if I do specify then it only brings data for that account.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please consider accepting it. If not, I suggest posting your own answer. (StackOverflow will let you accept your own answer after a couple of days.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending different queries with different where clauses in the application would be the best way to handle this.

However, if it *must* be done in the database, I think `COALESCE` will work for this particular case. Try this:

`WHERE account = COALESCE(@specificAccountNumber, account)`

`COALESCE` chooses the first non-`NULL` entry in its input list. What this should do is compare the `account` column with itself if `@specificAccountNumber` is `NULL`. I'm not sure if this will hurt the performance when `@specificAccountNumber` is specified. If `tableA` will be large in production, you should check the query plan.

Comment: Thank you. That's a nice solution to compare the account number in the table to itself. Totally couldn't think of that. I'm running this script file against several production tables. One thing I'm doing is using an object_id clause and @testing variable to control selecting data into temp tables. I also wanted to switch easily between full tale and specific account for qa purposes.

Comment: @VISQL If this doesn't work out performance-wise, you might be able to just use an if/else block that runs 2 different queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case statement in where clause something like this

```
declare
    -- only one of these @ vars will be used
    @specificAccountNumber int = NULL
    @specificAccountNumber int = 123456


select
    account
    ,accountinfo1
    ,accountinfo2
from tableA
where account = CASE 
                    WHEN  @specificAccountNumber IS NULL THEN account 
                    ELSE @specificAccountNumber END
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a nice solution to compare the account number in the table to itself.